# Excel VBA Create buttons to copy/rename sheets and whole workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a roadway design spreadsheet that can be used over and over again for hundreds of alignments.  I got the everything working with a master sheet to be copied and two sheets used as lookup tables.  I want to add two buttons in the corner that can be used to:

1) Copy the Master Sheet and rename it the alignmentname-##.  This will be within the current workbook and will be used for each curve in the roadway alignment.  It would be even better if there was a way to delete out these two buttons in the copied sheets.

2) A button to copy just the Master sheet, and two supplement sheets to a new workbook.

So far I have:

```
Sub Button10_Click()
    Worksheets("Master (DO NOT MODIFY)").Copy _
    Before:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Master (DO NOT MODIFY)")
End Sub
```

It works fine for now just creating a copy of the base file, but I have not been able to rename it.  The code for renaming the sheet is not working and I am not quite sure why.

```
Sheets(Count).Name = Range("H7").Value & "-" & Count
```

Where count is a public variable that goes up by one everytime a new curve is addedand H7 is the name of the alignment.

I have also played with the ActiveSheet. `activesheet` and `Worksheets`

Code for the first Button:

```
Public Count As Integer
Sub Button10_Click()
If Count = 0 Then
    Count = 1
End If

Dim ws As Worksheet

Worksheets("Master (DO NOT MODIFY)").Copy _
Before:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Master (DO NOT MODIFY)")

Set ws = ActiveSheet

ws.Name = Range("C2").Value & Count
Count = Count + 1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are trying? You cannot use `count` as the sheet is moved `before` the sheet and if you are incrementing the count then it will refer to the wrong sheet.

```
Sub Button10_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Worksheets("Master (DO NOT MODIFY)").Copy _
    Before:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Master (DO NOT MODIFY)")

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    ws.Name = Range("H7").Value & "-" & Count
End Sub
```

Regarding your 2nd question, you can try it like this. I am assuming that the master is not the last or the 2nd last sheet. Also there are two more sheets after the master.

```
Sub Button10_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsMaster As Worksheet
    Dim MyArray(1 To 3) As String
    Dim n As Long

    Set wsMaster = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master (DO NOT MODIFY)")

    wsMaster.Copy Before:=wsMaster

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    ws.Name = Range("H7").Value & "-" & Count

    n = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count

    MyArray(1) = wsMaster.Name
    MyArray(2) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(n - 1).Name
    MyArray(3) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(n).Name

    '~~> This will create a new workbook with the 3 sheets
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(MyArray).Copy
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  I didn't think of defining the active sheet like that.  I appended the original post with the Code for the first button.  Do you know how I can have it copy the last three sheets to a new workbook?

Comment: One moment. Updating the answer